# File not found using relative path with FreeMarker

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have the following folder structure

```
MyApp
  --WEB-INF
      --resources
        --partialFooter.jsp
        --myPartials
          --menu.jsp
      --views
        --index.jsp
```

and my index.jsp file

```
<#include "../resources/partialFooter.jsp"/>
<#include "../resources/myPartials/menu.jsp"/>
```

but this retruns file not found, in the both lines. Am I putting the right path, I also try with the absolute path but it was the same file not found error.

This is how I created my freemarker view resolvers

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"configuracion", "controladores", "seguridad"})
public class ConfigMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");

    }



@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
    return freeMarkerConfigurer;
}

@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {

    FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setCache(false);  

    return viewResolver;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't back out of the `/WEB-INF/views/` directory, because with `setTemplateLoaderPath` you set it as the root template directory. So instead you had to use `/WEB-INF/`, and then when you refer to the view templates, you have to start their names with `"/views/"` (`/views/index.jsp`). (Though the more common way is to put the included files into the "`lib`" subdirectory of the view templates, and then you can use the directory of the view templates as the root.)

BTW, you are probably using an outdated FreeMarker version, because for a while it explains this in the error message.